# PHP GD : Display English Text in Another Language

Tags: php, gd

If I add "Kamini" in GD, Can it display the text converted in Chinese or other language?

```
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, "somefont.ttf", "Kamini");
```

It displays the output as "Kamini". But Is that possible to get the output in another language?

Comment: What do you imagine the other output to be? Give an example.

Comment: I just got it. It depends on the fonts. I want some Chinese character related to that word.

Comment: So *"mouse"* in Russian would be *"мoусe"*, by your logic? Too bad it's actually *"мышь"*. Oh, and *"house"* would be... wait, there is no H in the Russian alphabet.

Comment: And then there are languages that do not even have the concept of a letter. In Chinese *"mouse"* is *"small rat"* ("小鼠"). In Japanese Katakana you could spell "マウセ", but that's three symbols, not five, and it still would not mean *"mouse"*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I know it is not right transition. It is meaningless to use. I am in need of meaning-less words in those language. I just planned to write a script to get those for English words

Comment: But you stated above that you wanted Chinese characters *related* to that word, not some meaningless gibberish. Maybe you could explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do translation on your own, GD display just text. There're many ways how to implement translation which would require several other questions, so just an example with [Gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), using [`_()` alias to `gettext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php), example borrowed from manual:

```
<?php
// Set language to German
putenv('LC_ALL=de_DE');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

// Specify location of translation tables
bindtextdomain("myPHPApp", "./locale");

// Choose domain
textdomain("myPHPApp");

// Translation is looking for in ./locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/myPHPApp.mo now

// Or use the alias _() for gettext()
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, "somefont.ttf", _("Kamini"));
```

You may use many others such as [`Zend_Locale`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html), method that is used by [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n) and many others.

Answer (score 0):

No. GD isn't a translator. You can change the font of a text, but this doesn't translate the text. if you want to some different symbols you have to use a font which contains them (maybe unicode) and translate them by hand.